# Is there a way to declare provide/inject in a Vue3 dynamic component, outside of the host setup function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am creating a `dynamic component` in `Vue3`.  I provide the `props` using `v-bind`.

```js
<component :is='MyComponent' v-bind='myProps' />
```

I would like to use the `provide/inject` feature.  How can I get my provided properties into the dynamic component.  My dynamic component calls `inject` in the `setup` function and expects a value to be `provided` for its child components.

Although this is not documented on Vue, I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
<component :is='MyComponent' v-bind='myProps' :provide='myProvidedProps'/>
```

And even tried putting the `provide` object inside the `props` object.

Comment: Could you explain what problem you're trying to solve with provide/inject? Because it sounds like you're unclear on what it does and when it should be used.

Comment: @tao Not unclear at all.  I have child components of the dynamic component that call "inject", and now that my root component is dynamic, I see no way to "provide".  Using provide/inject with a dynamic component... Says it all.

Comment: Also , I could use app level provide, but that is a hack and not specific enough, as it will leak to other components.

Comment: Furthermore, my dynamic component calls "inject".   Seems like an oversight on Vue3s part, because I can create the component dynamically using the API and us the `provide` option.

Comment: Provide provides to its descendants (in DOM). You call `provide()` in the ancestor and call `inject()` in the descendant. In essence, it's a mechanism to avoid prop-drilling. That's about it. It works exactly the same as CSS variables do. If you provide a var to a DOM element, you can use it anywhere in its descendants. If, at any level, you re-provide it, it's overwritten for that element's entire descendants DOM tree.

Comment: Both the provider and the consumer can be dynamic. As long as the consumer is a descendant of the provider, it (the consumer) gets the provided value. If this (or the docs) are not helpful, please create a *runnable* [mcve] with what you're attempting and, most likely, someone will spot what's amiss.

Comment: From what you described, it is possible (albeit questionable design) but there is not enough code here to really see whats wrong.  As ^ @tao mentioned

Comment: Its a question of api, not right or wrong. Do you know the api for this? Or if there is one at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the Vue3 source code, there is no way to indicate the `provide` spec to a `dynamic component` directly in the template.  It must be called in the setup function or option of the parent hosting the dynamic component, or in the dynamic component's setup or options.

The 2 options are:

1. You call `provide` on the component that hosts the dynamic component.

```
setup() {
  provide('message', 'hello')
}
```

```
<template>
  <component :is='myComponent' />
</template>
```

This does not work for me because my setup function has been called way before my dynamic component has been activated; I also need to set the component type and the provided value together.

2. Send the items to provide into the component as a prop, and let the dynamic component call provide on them.

```
function setComponent(someImportedComponent, providedValues) {
  myComponent.value = someImportedComponent
  myProps.value = {
    toProvide: providedValues
  }
}
```

```
<template>
  <component :is='myComponent' v-bind='myProps' />
</template>
```

MyComponent

```
setup() {
  for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(props.toProvide) ) {
    provide(key, value)
  }
}
```

Now this has its issues, because every dynamic component now needs to be responsible for being aware of and calling the passed in provide items.

## Solution 1

A way around each component needing to know about the provided values is to create an intermediate component that provides the values.

Providable (Intermediate Component)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {provide} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{
  is: any
  provide?: Record<string, any>
  [key: string]: any
}>()

if (props.provide) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props.provide)) {
    provide(key, value)
  }
}

const _props = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).filter(it => {
  return it[0] !== 'is' && it[0] !== 'provide'
}))
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="is" v-bind="_props"/>
</template>
```

Use it like this:

```
<template>
  <providable :is="myComponent" :provide='toProvide' v-bind='myProps' />
</template>
```

## Solution 2

An even cleaner solution is to create a wrapper component, similar to how `keep-alive` works.  The target component is simply put into the `default slot`.

Provide.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {provide} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{
  value: Record<string, any>
}>()

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props.value)) {
  provide(key, value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <slot name="default"/>
</template>
```

And use it like this:

```
<template>
  <provide value='toProvide'>
    <my-component v-bind='myProps' />
  </provide>
</template>
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for a built-in directive which takes two parameters (key and value) and provides the value under the key to its children. It doesn't exist, but writing [your own](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html) is not particularly difficult, IMHO. Until you answered, I was quite far off from understanding what you were looking for, and I don't think I was the only one.

Comment: Actually, it's not possible. Directives do not have a `setup` hook and `provide` can only be called inside `setup`. Which means you should probably use a store. I'd say the main problem with your request is that you're asking for syntax, rather than asking for potential solutions to a real problem.

Comment: 1. why on earth would i want to use a store for state that is confined to a component tree, and needs to propagage down to an unknown number of components?  this is EXACTLY what provide/inject is for.  2. i dont want a directive, i want a built in menchanism for 'component', same as ":is" which is also not a directive.  3. my stated solution is the closest i am going to get unless Vue implements this, because as you stated the directive lifecycle does not allow providing.